# How can I write a textfile into a syslog.1.gz file?

Tags: python, gzip, encode, syslog

```
import os,gzip, shutil

string = "Jul 28 14:09"
with gzip.open('/var/log/syslog.1.gz', 'rb') as f_in:
    with open('/home/usr/tmp.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
             if string not in str(line):
                    f_out.write(line)
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
with gzip.open('/var/log/syslog.1.gz', 'wb') as f:
    content = open('/home/usr/tmp.txt', 'rb').read()
    binary = content.encode()
    for line in binary:
        f.write(line)
```

I have tried this.
So I have write all of syslog.1.gz into the textfile, without the lines where the programm find the string. Then I want to overwrite the syslog.1.gz. Because I want to edit this logs and delete some specific logs.
But now I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/clear/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    with gzip.open('/var/log/syslog.1.gz', 'wb') as f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 53, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 163, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/syslog.1.gz'
```

Could you maybe help me?

Comment: Your problem is at the bottom.  You don't have permission to edit that file.  You need to use an account that has the permissions or change the permissions.  Often editing system log files will be done through `sudo`

Comment: Yes, I though that too. But after using sudo, I got still these error

Comment: oh yes, sorry. I found my mistake

Comment: What was your mistake?